# Convert bit to bin Xilinx file

Tags: fpga, xilinx

How can I convert a .bit (output from ISE Project Navigator) into a .bin file?

For what I understand, .bit files are similar to .bin but with a header that specifies things like the board and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than convert, it is possible to directly generate the bin file with ISE Project Navigator.

Before double clicking on "Generate Programmng File", first do secondary button on it and go to: "Process Properties..."

In there, under "General Options" tab check the **-g Binary** option.

[image]

I know there are other ways for converting the .bit file to .bin files directly but I don't know how.

Comment: Well, if you have a bit and you need a bin, then I think you can do that with promgen, possibly by taking the scenic route through mcs.  Or you can write a short script in the programming language of your choice to strip off the bit file header.  Interestingly enough, you can get away with writing the bit file verbatim to a serial config flash, header and all, as the actual bitstream contains synchronization information that enables the FPGA to ignore any 'junk' before the start of the bitstream.